# How to find a value from an array inside of an array?

Tags: php

I've got an array of this kind:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array (  [attribute_group_id] => 1
                [name] => Name 1 
                [attribute] => Array (  [0] => Array ( 
                                            [attribute_id] => 1 
                                            [name] => Attribute 1
                                            [text] => AAA) 
                                        [1] => Array ( 
                                            [attribute_id] => 2 
                                            [name] => Attribute 2 
                                            [text] => BBB ) 
                                        [2] => Array ( 
                                            [attribute_id] => 3 
                                            [name] => Attribute 3 
                                            [text] => CCC ) 
                                        ) ) )
```

I would like to extract only BBB text here, but if I construct the foreach function it outputs something like BBB BBB BBB (example below):

```
foreach ($p_atts as $p_att) {
  foreach ($p_att['attribute'] as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute['attribute_id'] = '2') {
       $out .= $attribute['text'];
    }
  }
}
```

I would be glad if you could help!

Comment: Have you tried to use `foreach`loop that will help you?

Comment: Just added code below. I think I misuse the code, it should be constructed otherwise.

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812093/php-searching-in-multidimensional-array-of-unknown-depth

Comment: You are not comparing the attributes in the if. Should be `===` instead you are overwriting the value.

Comment: array_column($array, 'text');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must two equals in if statement.

```
foreach ($p_atts as $p_att) {
  foreach ($p_att['attribute'] as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute['attribute_id'] == '2') {
       $out .= $attribute['text'];
    }
  }
}
```